# log4j logging not working with REST, and Jackson jars

Tags: json, rest, spring-mvc, log4j, jackson

I am working on a Spring MVC project with REST, and Jackson jars. I am just trying to test some logging using log4j, but it is not working i.e it does not give any response to the console or to the file.

Here is my 'log4j.properties' file:

```
# LOG4J configuration
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, Appender1, Appender2

# Redirects log messages to console
log4j.appender.Appender1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.Appender1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Appender1.layout.ConversionPattern=%-7p %d [%t] %c %x - %m%n

# Redirects log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.Appender2=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.Appender2.File=C:/temp/logFile.log
log4j.appender.Appender2.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Appender2.layout.ConversionPattern=%-7p %d [%t] %c %x - %m%n
```

Here is my REST controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/student/")
public class WebController {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(WebController.class);

    @Autowired
    StudentDao studentDao;

    @RequestMapping(value="/getList", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Student> getStudentList() {     

        // testing logger -----start----------
        logger.info("This is an info log entry");
        if(logger.isDebugEnabled()){
            logger.debug("method getStudentList() is executed!");
        }
        logger.error("This is an error log entry");
        // testing logger ------------end ------------

        List<Student> studentList = studentDao.getDataList();
        return studentList;
    }
}
```

I have a database that have a list of students, and when I call '........./ProjectName/student/getList' through the browser it gives the list of students in the json format, but I do not get any of the test log messages either on the console or on the log file. I assume this is happening because it can show only json format.

Any ideas on how can I show the log statements?

Please let me know, would appreciate any help regarding this.

Thanks
-Prachi

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are not seeing any log messages is most likely because you do not have `log4.properties` on your classpath.

Comment: Thanks @David, this works. But I had to remove and add log4j.properties to the classpath everytime I added a logger statement to a different method in my WebController file.

Comment: The reason for that is when you are recompiling the Java file `WebController.java` the compiler is cleaning out your output directory and deleting the `log4j.properties`. Therefore, you should put the `log4j.properties` in a source directory, e.g. `src/main/resources`